# Make oauth2 synonym of oauth-2.0

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

There are two tags for OAuth 2:

- [oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth2) (583)
- [oauth-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth-2.0) (9595)

Both because it’s the more popular tag and for consistency with [oauth-1.0a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth-1.0a), the former should be made a synonym of the latter.

Answer (score 1):

This seems fairly clear cut; done ([oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth2) -> [oauth-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth-2.0)). If someone comes up with a reason that it shouldn't be synonymized, we can undo it.